# How to make a socketio event return value from a second client

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io

I want to return value received in callback.
client1 emits some_event to server. Server emits some_event to client2 and expects callback (aka ack). Client2 receives some_event and returns it's response (which goes to server in callback). Server returns value of callback from client2 to client1.

I use socket.io-client (JS) on clients and fastapi_socketio (python) on server.

I tried to achieve this like that:
client:

```js
export async function fun(data: string): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    socket.emit("some_event", data, (response: boolean) => {
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
}

socket.on("some_event", () => {
    return "client2 response"
})
```

server:

```py
@socket_manager.on("some_event")  # type: ignore
async def fun(sid: str, data: Any) -> bool:
    response = "buzz"
    async def callback(callback_data: Any):
            nonlocal response
            response = callback_data
    await socket_manager.emit(
            "some_event", to=client2_sid, callback=callback
        )
    return response
```

this doesn't work, the server returns unchanged value ("buzz") to client1

Comment: I managed to resolve this. For future reference - there's a special message both on client side (JS) and on server side (py) which returns a value (as opposed to regular emit, which doesn;t return anything.

JS - socket.emitWithAck(<event_name>, args): Promise<Any>
this is promise based method so you can simply
```js
const response = await socket.emitWithAck("some_event")
```
PY - socket_manager.call(<event_name>) -- (also asynchronous)
```py
const response = await socket_manager.call("some_event", data=args, to=receiver_sid)
```

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. The server gets timeout error regardless of long enough timeout period. client2 does send the response but server seems to not be getting it.